# Getting Clock/Time information from PC to an STM32F4

Tags: debian, sync, time, clock, microcontroller

Assume I connect a microcontroller board (like an STM32F4) to a PC via USB. Is there anything in the USB communication protocol that contains host clock data? In other words, can I sync the microcontroller to the PC clock just by hooking up to USB?

If that's not possible, could you suggest some clever minimal-effort way to get the clock info from PC to the STM32F4?

I guess I could always write some software to run on the PC in the background and provide that info to the STM32F4, and I'll do that if I must, but I'd like to avoid that.

I could also use a network shield and have the STM32F4 query the PC over the network, but I'd like to keep cost and complexity down by not using any extra shields.

I could also have the STM32F4 run its own clock base, but that's not an option - it must be synced to this particular PC down to the second, even if the PC itself is out of sync with NTP.